# UWP CommandBar - Content is completely separate context?

Tags: c#, uwp, hamburger-menu, commandbar

I've been trying to implement Microsoft's hamburger pattern in my own way for some time.

Final result was the following:

- AppShell for containing current page and hamburger menu (menu always visible)
- In Appshell, Grid with two rows: one 48px in height, one one-start height.
- In first row, added a commandbar (global), and hamburger button (togglebutton with custom style for being 48px wide and tall, with the hamburger fonticon in the center)
- In second row, SplitView with a ListBox on the Pane, and a Frame in the Content.

This way one has control over the content, while displaying a global menu and command bar. On the Navigated event of the Frame, I update the CommandBar to pull the primary and secondary commands from the Frame's Content's properties (I use a custom page control with those properties), and the content of the CommandBar (which is, of now, a single TextBlock with binding).

However, I wanted to move the ToggleButton into the CommandBar. It worked nicely, except the binding (IsChecked of ToggleButton is bound to IsPaneOpen of SplitView) does not work. I use the regular ElementName targeting, and would prefer to not to use a ViewModel property.

Does the CommandBar.Content use a different context? Or why doesn't the ElementName reference work?

Comment: do you use `x:Bind` ? have you set the `Mode` property correctly?

Comment: I use regular `Binding`, not `x:Bind`. Mode is set properly (TwoWay), but it's like the property change never fires. If I copy-paste the exact code of the ToggleButton out of the CommandBar, it works fine. If inside the Content of the Commandbar, it stops working.

Comment: have you tried reversing the binding? What I mean by that is: Instead of having a two way binding on the ToggleButton have a one-way binding like `IsPaneOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Toggle}"`

Comment: Yes I did, with similar result. It's like the control in the CommandBar content does not exist. Funny thing though - I bind a TextBlock's Text to the Frame's Content's Title property (I use a custom Page control), and THAT works.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<Page
    x:Class="StackOverflowTests.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="48"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CommandBar>
            <CommandBar.Content>
                <AppBarToggleButton Icon="Globe" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=SplitView,Path=IsPaneOpen,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </CommandBar.Content>
        </CommandBar>
        <SplitView Grid.Row="1" Name="SplitView" IsPaneOpen="{x:Bind Appbarbutton.IsChecked.Value,Mode=OneWay}">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <ListBox>
                    <ListBoxItem>Foo</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>Bar</ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
            </SplitView.Pane>
            <SplitView.Content>
                <TextBlock>stuff here</TextBlock>
            </SplitView.Content>
        </SplitView>
    </Grid>
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <CommandBar.Content>
                <AppBarToggleButton Name="Appbarbutton" Icon="Home" />
            </CommandBar.Content>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
</Page>
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but it kinda defeats the purpose of built-in CommandBar.
If you use CommandBar in the page (<Page.BottomAppBar>), the binding doesn't work.

Comment: If you read the question, that's exactly what he's asking for, `CommandBar` in `Grid`

Comment: @TomShane I added another example to show, this is also possible in the Pages Bottom/Top AppBar without `DataContext` setting

Answer (score 0):

Only way, how I was able to bind to AppBarToggleButton was to set the DataContext in the code behind.

XAML:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
  <CommandBar x:Name="CommandBar">
    <AppBarToggleButton x:Name="Button" IsChecked="{Binding IsPaneOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" Icon="Home" Label="Button"/>
  </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Code behind:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
  Button.DataContext = SplitView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have bind DataContext:
Example:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar >
    <CommandBar x:Name="commandBar" DataContext="{Binding}">
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0">
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Confirmation.AvailableValues}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemBase}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="{Binding Value.DisplayName}" Command="{Binding DataContext.Confirm, ElementName=commandBar}" CommandParameter="{Binding Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                <Line Margin="5" X1="0" X2="1000" Y1="0" Y2="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="2"  Stroke="#888888"   StrokeThickness="1" ></Line>
            </StackPanel>
        </CommandBar.Content>
    </CommandBar>

</Page.BottomAppBar>
```